# Power Radiated by an antenna

Tags: power, rf, antenna, electromagnetism, electromagnetic

I have read that the power radiated by an antenna is equal to the flux of the Poynting vector through **any closed surface** that includes the antenna.

This fact is for instance exploited to calculate the radiated power in the Fraunhofer Region, in which the Poynting vector has a radial direction: if we choose a sphere as our closed surface, we get:

[image: Radiated Power =]

I do not understand why we may calculate the flux by choosing any closed surface: why is the radiated power independent from the choice of the surface?

Comment: At any distance from an antenna, if you enclosed it spherically, do you see that you will always get the same power?

Comment: Is this due to the fact that P depends on 1/r^2? Or to something about conservation of energy?

Comment: Conservation of energy. The power per sq metre thins out at greater distance but the total power over the bigger surface area is the same as the total power over a smaller surface area. Power per sq metre is related to \$\frac{1}{r^2}\$ because E field and H field reduce with distance linearly and power is E x H fields hence you get the r^2 relationship.